# How to upload unstructured data into Google Storage that has latin-1 encoding

Tags: utf-8, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, iso-8859-1

We have unstructured data, however already transformed into tabular structures, that we want to upload to GCP Storage in order to process them with bigQuery, feeding our data teams. However, our data is not encoded in UTF-8 and it does have all sort of special spanish characters. So everytime we tried to upload the data, encoding stuff happens, and our data just f"$#"# up. So I was wondering, if anybody here knows an API that can help us with our issue; or if the is an existant method or pipeline within GCP to handle this kind of data transformation.

Spanish Characters such as: ñ, ó, ¡

Summary

*We want to ingest a lot of data with Latin-1 encoding in our GCP instance. How we can do it , to preserve the characters while being able to be used by Bigquery and Friends.*

PD: We can not transform it UTF-8 before uploading, because the data is too big, and we would like to process(it) within the cloud!

Comment: Can you say more about what library or tool you're using to upload your data?

Comment: I understand that the first issue is when uploading to GCS, probably because the filenames contain invalid characters. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems#converting-filenames-to-unicod) there are some open-source tools available to convert filenames.

Comment: @DonCharlie - can you clarify whether the problem is with Latin-1 encoded filenames or content? I assumed it was the data itself, given your comment about data being too big to convert. If the data itself is encoded with Latin-1, that should work fine at the GCS service, which is why I asked what library or tool you are using to upload the data.

Comment: Thank you guys for the interest! The problem is with the Data content Itself rather than the filenames. We are using a third-party API but it is not working. We would love to know if there is any suggested tool that can help us uploading the data, preserving the integrity of it. We are automating the process using Pub/Sub, but we are failing to achive the initial ingest of the already existant data(The data are mostly complains for a big company in Latam, therefore we need to preserve the special characters)

Comment: As @MikeSchwartz mentioned, the data itself shouldn't give you any problem when uploading the files to GCS, but the filename will.

Comment: Just to clarify, your workflow is first uploading the data to a GCS Bucket and then process that data with BigQuery?

Comment: @DonCharlie - If the problem is with the data, it sounds like the tool/lib you're using to upload the data doesn't correctly handle Latin-1 encoding. Can you try using gsutil? Or, if it needs to be done programmatically, can you switch to using one of the gcloud libraries (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)?